# Old Router as AP - choosing AP IP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

My ISP modem/router is connected via powerline to a second router. 
On second router (AP) I have disabled DHCP, I have connected it with powerline using the LAN port (so not the port marked as internet going to WAN). I set the AP LAN IP to be 192.168.1.99 ( the main router is 192.168.1.1).

I have not made any setting changes to the main router.

Currently I have given my AP the IP of .1.99, which in practice means it should never be a problem, as we wont have that many devices connected. Although I was wondering if its possible to make sure that the 192.168.1.99 will always be reserved for it and not given out. In theory the routers will always be connected so this should not happen I guess, but still want to be safe

Also, is there a way to test which AP I am currently connected to?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the MAC address of your AP
2. On your mail router > Lan configuration
3. Reserve that MAC address with that IP
   You might already see this one listed as active client so you might be able to copy paste
4. Restart your AP and see if it's automatically getting .99

   5. Change Lan mode to bridge

***Changes on AP***
Set AP to forward DHCP requests to your main router

Comment: OK will try asap. Also, if IP is given, does it mean the AP cannot give internet, or that the AP admin page will not be accessible ?

Comment: AP can further give our internet set Lan mode on main router to bridge instead of nat

Comment: AP does not show up on DHCP address list of main router, although it is accessible at .1.99... hmm

Comment: Try just adding it and then bouncing to see if it automatically getting the ip